# Data variable return as [object Object]

Tags: php, jquery

I have a button with data :

```
data-boutique-id="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_ID());
```

In my main.js i have 2 jQuery functions using those 2 variables :

```
$fav = $('.fav-btn'),
boutiqueId = $fav.data('boutique-id');
```

My `on('click')` function is working fine, it does return the `data-boutique-id`. Bu my `ready()` function is not working and the variable `boutiqueId` is returning `[object Object]` instead of the Id. There must be something i don't know.

```
var $fav = $('.fav-btn'),
  boutiqueId = $fav.data('boutique-id');

$fav.ready(function(theBoutique) {     
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      action: 'check-fav',
      boutiqueId: theBoutique
    },
    url: '/wp-json/fav_ajax/v1/manage_fav/'
  }).done(function(_data) { 
    console.log(_data);
  });
});
```

```php
function manage_fav_rest_route() 
{
  // Path to ajax 
  register_rest_route(
    'fav_ajax/v1',
    '/manage_fav/',
    array(
      'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
      'callback' => 'handle_rest_call'
    )
  );
}

function handle_rest_call() 
{
  $the_boutique = $_GET['boutiqueId'];
  $the_action =  $_GET['action'];

  if ('check-fav' == $the_action) 
  {
    return $the_boutique;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no `ready` event for any element except for document: jQuery's `.ready()` event for the document is simply a shorthand to check for DOMContentLoaded. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: the first argument of the callback in ready is the jQuery object, so theBoutique === $. ready work also with image (written in the doc here: https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @progysm i mean, it works, but it's not actually looking at the image for anything. It just as well could have been any other selector.

Comment: @Terry What i'm trying to do is a "add to list" button. This button has a click function that send the current post id to php using ajax. The php will then create a CPT "added to list" and return to the front end and change the button's class. This function is all working correctly. But now i want to have a ready function that will check if there's an existing CPT "added to list" for this current page. So this is why i'm trying to get the data to php but the data is currently considered as [object Object] which is not the case for the click function using the same logic and variables.

Comment: If `data()` is returning an object, then the value you are putting into it with the html is a json string.  `data()` will try to auto parse the value of the attribute into something not a string

Comment: Wait, so is the data being sent to php is [object Object]? If so, have you tried $(document).ready?

Comment: **Read the previous comments. The first two specifically.** The entire problem is that instead of passing the id to php, the OP is passing the jquery object to php. jquery doesn't know what to do with said object, so it stringifies it to `[object Object]`. so php receives the string `[object Object]`. ***You are mis-using the .ready method.***

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an event with the function inside.

```
$fav.ready(function( event ) {
    console.log( "event ready!" );

  // Validate user is logged in
  if( isLoggedIn) {
    checkFav( boutiqueId );
  }
  });

  function checkFav( theBoutique ) {
    console.log( "function ready!" );

        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          action : 'check-fav',
          boutiqueId : theBoutique
        },
       url: '/wp-json/fav_ajax/v1/manage_fav/'
```